# Сравнение эксель файлов в тестах JUnit

Tags: java, excel, junit, apache-poi

Нужно сравнить несколько десятков пар огромных excel файлов, причем не построчно, а проверять, что все строки из одного файла входят в другой (потому что они перемешаны).
Как это сделать проще всего? Сейчас в проекте уже имеется Apache POI, но как бы я его не использовал, возникают Out of Memory ошибки различного вида.

---

Вот один из способов чтения.

```
private Set<String> readRowsFromExcel(XSSFWorkbook workbook, int sheetNumber) {
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(sheetNumber);
        Set<String> rows = new HashSet<>();
        for (Row row : sheet) {
            StringBuilder cells = new StringBuilder();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                        cells.append(String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue()));
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        cells.append(cell.getStringCellValue());
                        break;
                }
                cells.append(" | ");
            }
            rows.add(cells.toString());
        }
        return rows;
}
```

Дальше предполагается вот такой код:

```
final Set<String> expRows = readRowsFromExcel(expWorkbook, 0);
final Set<String> actRows = readRowsFromExcel(actWorkbook, 0);

if (expRows.size() != actRows.size()) {
    //бросаем ошибку
            } else {
    for (final String row : expRows) {
        if (!actRows.contains(row)) {
            //бросаем ошибку
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Все это зависает на самом большом файле (4 МБ), хотя вроде здесь ничего особенного

Comment: Обычно проверка "все элементы из А есть в Б" реализуется через множества (`Set`). В базовых классах это наверняка лучше оптимизировано, чем в интерфейсах для .xls. Попробуйте выгрузить строки из одного файла в Set,  потом из другого, потом проверить.

Comment: Глупый вопрос, но на всякий случай спрошу: а база есть какая-нибудь в доступности\"недалеко" от xls файлов?

Comment: Ну и с точки зрения тестирования: это уже слабо похоже на юнит-тест. Стоит уделить внимание репрезентативным сообщениям об ошибках. Т.е. предположим, что тест провалился, не все строки нашлись во втором файле. Что выводить в результатах? Только первую строку, которая не нашлась (это будет fail-fast test) или продолжать проверку и выдавать все?

Comment: @Nick Volynkin тоже задумывался над тем, что выдавать в результатах, полагаю, оптимально будет вывести первое несовпадение, чтобы просто отследить регрессии. Надо же заметить ошибки в остальных файлах, а стена текста этому не способствует)

Comment: @user3195373 не, с БД данная функциональность не связана. А чем поможет использование?

Comment: Ну и чтобы OOM отследить - может выложите минимальный пример кода, воспроизводящего проблему? Без него на вопрос сложно ответить.

Comment: @TheSN по своей практике если большие файлы и сформированы машиной/клиентами с предварительной обработкой, то сливаю в базу и там уже дальше обрабатываю.

Comment: @Nick Volynkin приложил код